# Comparison between bond length of platinum and titanium oxides

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, transition-metals, oxides

This question comes from a problem sheet I recently had.

It concerns the fact that Pt-O bond lengths are typically longer than Ti-O ones, even though the radii of the two metals are similar.

My rationale is that as Ti d-orbitals are more contracted than the ones of Pt, it would form shorter bonds for that reason. I was wondering whether there is something else to it.

Comment: hint: TiO2 has Ti-O about 2A, but TiO has Ti-O about 3A . On the other hand, both PtO2 and PtO have close Pt-O about 2A

Comment: @permeakra is this to suggest that due to the absence of d-electrons in TiO2, such a compound would be with significantly more ionic character, thus having the atoms closer for electrostatic reasons?